# how to load script files in Helmet tag gastby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

I want to load some script files in `Helmet` tag using Gatsby.js , the script files are something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('consent', 'default', {
    ad_storage: 'denied',
    analytics_storage: 'denied',
    wait_for_update: 1500,
  });
  gtag('set', 'ads_data_redaction', true);
</script>
```

This is my SEO component :

```
 <Helmet>
      <title>{metaTitle}</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <script id="CookieConsent" src="https://policy.app.cookieinformation.com/uc.js" data-culture="EN" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=321012880"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('consent', 'default', {
    ad_storage: 'denied',
    analytics_storage: 'denied',
    wait_for_update: 1500,
  });
  gtag('set', 'ads_data_redaction', true);
</script>
    </Helmet>
```

when I use this directly inside the `Helmet` tag , this will cause an error , better said , the script code will not be read
any idea how to solve this ? or is there any alternative to load script files in Gatsby ?
Thanks

Comment: what error does it show when you use it inside the helmet tag?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/ThMvtQ2/Screenshot-5.png . The script is not readable in the Helmet tag

Comment: can you post your code on how you do it if its inside the helmet tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gatsby's Script API: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-script/

Your example code then would look like this:

```
import { Script } from "gatsby"

<Script id="gtag-config">
  {`
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('consent', 'default', {
      ad_storage: 'denied',
      analytics_storage: 'denied',
      wait_for_update: 1500,
    });
    gtag('set', 'ads_data_redaction', true);
  `}
</Script>
```

Then use this snippet in whichever React component you want. Please note that you'll need to add an `id` to the component for inline scripts (see https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-script/#inline-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

In Helmet 3.0.0 you can use `innerHTML`:

```
<Helmet 
  script={[{ 
    type: 'text/javascript', 
    innerHTML: `
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag('consent', 'default', {
        ad_storage: 'denied',
        analytics_storage: 'denied',
        wait_for_update: 1500,
      });
      gtag('set', 'ads_data_redaction', true);
    `
  }]} 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks , I also have another script to add , so how to manage to do that with this method ?

Comment: what script?. just add it below